# Transfer Panasonic raw files (and videos) to android

Tags: file-transfer, android, panasonic, wireless

I am looking for a way to transfer raw images and video to my android phone from my Panasonic camera. Wirelessly is preferred but using cables should be ok as well. What I'm not really looking for us popping out the SD and using a USB/SD converter on my phone. Over the web may be ok, but sort of my last resort because many times I'm without connection or really slow internet. But I guess if that is my only options, it is what it is. This is why I'm checking with the community to make sure I didn't overlook something.

I already have the Panasonic image app for android. It works for supported file types. Though unsupported file types seem to be RAW images and video footage. Or maybe just the format I'm saving it in. There are times when I'm out and about and would like to transfer a quick video to my phone so that I can send it to someone or share it on social media, or import it into Lightroom Mobile and/or Adobe Clip. Is there a way to do this for the unsupported images/videos?

Equipment details:

- Phone: HTC Google Pixel XL
- Android: 7.1.2
- Camera: Panasonic GX-8
- Panasonic Image App: 1.10.2

Things I have tried are the Panasonic Image App for Android. I have made sure the app and Android is up-to-date. Though I am unsure about my cameras firmware. I have not changed it since initial unboxing, which is about 6 months ago. Maybe a new firmware update has resolved this.

Things I am looking into further are:

- Updating my camera's firmware
- A way to wirelessly mount camera to my android and access the camera filesystem that way
- Using the HDMI or AV out ports on camera to my android
- LUMIX Club

One additional note is that I am an ex-software engineer comfortable with low-level programming, so these types of solutions are ok as well. Though I'd prefer to not fully write my own android application just for this.

Comment: The likely reason raw still image files and video files are not supported is due to the very large file sizes. Transferring such files wirelessly would kill your camera's batteries in no time.

Comment: I don't have any answers for you on wireless, I've only ever been able to do this on my Canon via doing a host mode usb connection from my phone via OTG cables.  I don't really know Panasonic though.

Comment: A RAW file is not an image, it is a file of data that requires software  to read or convert the data in order to create an image from the data . Do you have software on your phone to to convert that data to an image view-able on your phone?

Comment: @Alaskaman You are correct with the RAW images. This is probably a separate situation, and would require different tools as you pointed out. Some software to convert the data to an image. I still have the same question for video though. As Michael Clark pointed out, yes it will kill your battery. But I don't think I am looking at doing this that heavy. The footage I'm looking to transfer is usually around 10 to 20 seconds. I think my phone can handle this under most situations.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having problems pulling videos and RAWs out of my DMC-LX10, also with a Pixel XL. My small 16gb cards will mount directly on the phone with the help of a USB-C card reader, but my larger cards won't mount and want to reformat. If I let the phone reformat the card, the camera won't read it. Can't seem to get EXFAT to work properly on both devices at the same time.

Comment: You want to share RAW files to social media? Did I read that correctly?

Comment: @kanzanaki Not quite. I'm getting errors from the Panasonic app with the supported feature of "Transfer to phone" so that I can use VSCO or Lightroom Mobile, or Adobe Clip, or anything else for that matter. I simply can't get it to my phone. I just need a way to get RAW AND Video footage file to Android. Even if it is converting it on the camera first. It's mostly video footage I care about. I'm trying to make a quick movie on Adobe Clip. I just can't get it to my phone through supported Panasonic app, or a number of other wifi android xfer apps.

Comment: Most "File Browser"/"File Manager" apps for android allow for wireless LAN access using SMB (Samba). So if you plug in the SD card and share the folder, you should be able to access it from the Android device. I used ES File Explorer before, but it looks like it has gotten a little too commercial for my taste, so don't take that as a recommendation. Just an example. RAW support is the big hurdle.

Comment: Thanks @Yorik. While this somewhat gets me there, I am looking for offline solutions. Panasonic's app allows this. And please note, it's not necessarily just RAW. I'm actually looking for video as well. It's also the feature of being able to view the images and videos before transferring them, as they can take a while to transfer. Most android file browsers will just show you the file names. I'm sure there are some out there, but again they usually have to have a LAN connection.

Answer (score 1):

I think Gnarbox might be what you are looking for. It allows you to edit/process files on the go using just your mobile phone/tablet

**Update - solution 2**

Check also if Eye-Fi direct is compatible with your camera and your mobile phone.

Comment: Does it wirelessly transfer the file from my GX8 to my phone? I can edit the files once on my phone with existing apps. But I can not get them to my phone. Right now my solution is plug the SD into my laptop, Import into Adobe Lightroom, then plug in my Android, then transfer the file over, then open up the desired existing mobile apps (Adobe Clip).

Desired result is transfer over the video clip within the native Panasonic (or something as close as possible) wirelessly (like it already does with photos) to my phone with video files.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have one to verify. But I think you connect the camera via usb to  gnarbox. Then you open your mobile phone, do any editing you want with the gnarbox app (or copy the files to your phone if you want to use your own editing app wirelessly) and finally you send files to social media.

Comment: So you just use camera, gnarbox, mobile phone. No laptop is needed as intermediate link.

Comment: Also I just thought eye-fi direct!

Comment: These are helpful. I think probably the closest I'm going to find to solving my issue. I think the issue really is just a feature request to Panasonic. It's already doing EXACTLY what I want. With the exception of some file formats. I don't have to buy extra equipment, I don't have to even take out the SD card. I can have a faster SD card than what Eye-fi has. It just transfers straight from camera to phone. Such a shame, it was so close. Maybe in the future they will add this support.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success copying all raw files by connecting the Panasonic's Android "Image App" and initiating a batch copy (click "Image Transfer" button) once the Wifi is established. Unfortunately, this mechanism does not let you choose the files you want. Everything is copied.

I then use Lightroom Mobile on my phone to edit the raw images. Works like a charm.

Comment: This is interesting. I've tried the same thing with my GX85, and RAWs were not an option to copy over. JPGs worked great, though. I wonder if this is a deliberate software limitation imposed by Panasonic on all but top tier "Pro" models.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the best solution is to shoot RAW + JPG. You can transfer the jpg to Android but keep the RAW files for later post-processing.

Comment: OP was looking to transfer both photos and videos to their Android. Your answer hits on the photo part, but what about videos?